# .Net SMTP client not working with postfix smtp server on linux

Tags: c#, linux, .net-core, smtp

I am using .Net Core 3.1 below given is my simple code

```
static async System.Threading.Tasks.Task Main(string[] args)
{
    var smtpClient = new SmtpClient()
    {
        Host = "leadsearch.localdomain",
        Port = 25,
        EnableSsl = true,
        UseDefaultCredentials = true
    };
    var msg = new MailMessage("noreply@myhost.com", "mypersonalemail@gmail.com");
    msg.Subject = "Sent from Abdul Moiz";
    msg.Body = "<h1>Moiz Body of msg</h1>";
    msg.IsBodyHtml = true;
    await smtpClient.SendMailAsync(msg);
    Console.WriteLine("Done!!!");
}
```

However, my postfix is configured correctly and is sending emails, I tested it using below command.

```
echo "This is the body of the email" | mail -s "This is the subject line" mypersonalemail@gmail.com
```

Then I went into my inbox and found email in the spam folder I tried running it various times from terminal, its working perfectly fine from the terminal. But when I try to send it using the c# code given above I get this error.

```
Unhandled exception. System.Net.Mail.SmtpException: Failure sending mail.
 ---> System.Net.Internals.SocketExceptionFactory+ExtendedSocketException (00000005, 0xFFFDFFFF): Name or service not known
   at System.Net.Dns.InternalGetHostByName(String hostName)
   at System.Net.Dns.ResolveCallback(Object context)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw(Exception source)
   at System.Net.Dns.HostResolutionEndHelper(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Net.Dns.EndGetHostAddresses(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.DoDnsCallback(IAsyncResult result, MultipleAddressConnectAsyncResult context)
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.DnsCallback(IAsyncResult result)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw(Exception source)
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.EndConnect(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient.EndConnect(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Net.Mail.SmtpConnection.ConnectAndHandshakeAsyncResult.InitializeConnectionCallback(IAsyncResult result)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw(Exception source)
   at System.Net.Mail.SmtpConnection.ConnectAndHandshakeAsyncResult.End(IAsyncResult result)
   at System.Net.Mail.SmtpTransport.EndGetConnection(IAsyncResult result)
   at System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.ConnectCallback(IAsyncResult result)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at MailSenderConsoleApp.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\Users\moiz.baig\source\repos\MailSenderConsoleApp\MailSenderConsoleApp\Program.cs:line 25
   at MailSenderConsoleApp.Program.<Main>(String[] args)
Aborted (core dumped)
```

when I check my localhost SMTP server hostname as mentioned [here](http://www.postfix.org/STANDARD_CONFIGURATION_README.html) I got the following result

```
postconf -d myhostname
myhostname = leadsearch.localdomain
```

My Linux OS detail where my build is deployed:

```
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS
Release:        18.04
Codename:       bionic
```

I don't know what I am doing wrong but this is not working at all pleas

Answer (score 0):

Your error output says `at System.Net.Dns.InternalGetHostByName(String hostName)`.

This means that the machine on which you run this code does not know what IP address corresponds to **leadsearch.localdomain**. Of course on linux it does, it is itself.

So 2 choices. Configure a DNS to respond with the proper address for leadsearch.localdomain, or define it in your local hosts file.

Your local hosts file is in `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts`